# Calculate hourly distance travelled from smaller time-stamped intervals for plotting

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and I find difficult to analyze temporal data. Here's a `head()` sample of the dataset I'm working with, which has thousands of rows:

```
> head(datanet)
   Date & Time [Local]   meters
1:    18/06/2018 03:01 45.74068
2:    18/06/2018 03:06 15.22141
3:    18/06/2018 03:08 15.95937
4:    18/06/2018 03:12 22.53557
5:    18/06/2018 03:16 12.03683
6:    18/06/2018 03:20 18.73813
```

On the column `Date & Time [Local]` are the time stamps and the column `meters` has values on distance travelled (in meters) between the time stamp on the same row and the next row.

Ex: `45.74068` meters were travelled between `18/06/2018 03:01` and `18/06/2018 03:06`

I would like to create a dataset that I can use to `plot()` the average number of distance travelled for every hour of the day (from 00:00 to 23:00) based on the `datanet` dataset. A possible output would be (without `meters` values filled in):

```
> head(output)
   Time    meters
1:  00:00 
2:  01:00  
3:  02:00  
4:  03:00  
5:  04:00  
6:  05:00
```

The `output` dataset would be based on the hourly daily averages for all days in the `datanet` dataset.

I'll upload a larger sample of `datanet` below:

```
> dput(datanet)
structure(list(`Date & Time [Local]` = c("18/06/2018 03:01", 
"18/06/2018 03:06", "18/06/2018 03:08", "18/06/2018 03:12", "18/06/2018 03:16", 
"18/06/2018 03:20", "18/06/2018 03:24", "18/06/2018 03:28", "18/06/2018 03:33", 
"18/06/2018 03:36", "18/06/2018 03:40", "18/06/2018 03:45", "18/06/2018 03:48", 
"18/06/2018 03:52", "18/06/2018 03:56", "18/06/2018 04:00", "18/06/2018 04:04", 
"18/06/2018 04:08", "18/06/2018 04:12", "18/06/2018 04:16", "18/06/2018 04:20", 
"18/06/2018 04:24", "18/06/2018 04:28", "18/06/2018 04:32", "18/06/2018 04:36", 
"18/06/2018 04:40", "18/06/2018 04:44", "18/06/2018 04:48", "18/06/2018 04:52", 
"18/06/2018 04:56", "18/06/2018 05:00", "18/06/2018 05:04", "18/06/2018 05:08", 
"18/06/2018 05:12", "18/06/2018 05:16", "18/06/2018 05:20", "18/06/2018 05:24", 
"18/06/2018 05:28", "18/06/2018 05:32", "18/06/2018 05:36", "18/06/2018 05:40", 
"18/06/2018 05:44", "18/06/2018 05:48", "18/06/2018 05:52", "18/06/2018 05:56", 
"18/06/2018 06:00", "18/06/2018 06:05", "18/06/2018 06:08", "18/06/2018 06:12", 
"18/06/2018 06:16", "18/06/2018 06:20", "18/06/2018 06:24", "18/06/2018 06:28", 
"18/06/2018 06:32", "18/06/2018 06:36", "18/06/2018 06:40", "18/06/2018 06:44", 
"18/06/2018 06:48", "18/06/2018 06:52", "18/06/2018 06:57", "18/06/2018 07:01", 
"18/06/2018 07:04", "18/06/2018 07:08", "18/06/2018 07:12", "18/06/2018 07:17", 
"18/06/2018 07:20", "18/06/2018 07:24", "18/06/2018 07:28", "18/06/2018 07:32", 
"18/06/2018 07:36", "18/06/2018 07:40", "18/06/2018 07:44", "18/06/2018 07:48", 
"18/06/2018 07:52", "18/06/2018 07:56", "18/06/2018 08:00", "18/06/2018 08:04", 
"18/06/2018 08:08", "18/06/2018 08:12", "18/06/2018 08:16", "18/06/2018 08:20", 
"18/06/2018 08:24", "18/06/2018 08:28", "18/06/2018 08:32", "18/06/2018 08:36", 
"18/06/2018 08:40", "18/06/2018 08:44", "18/06/2018 08:48", "18/06/2018 08:52", 
"18/06/2018 08:56", "18/06/2018 09:00", "18/06/2018 09:04", "18/06/2018 09:08", 
"18/06/2018 09:12", "18/06/2018 09:16", "18/06/2018 09:20", "18/06/2018 09:24", 
"18/06/2018 09:28", "18/06/2018 09:32", "18/06/2018 09:40", "18/06/2018 09:44", 
"18/06/2018 09:48", "18/06/2018 09:52", "18/06/2018 09:56", "18/06/2018 10:00", 
"18/06/2018 10:05", "18/06/2018 10:08", "18/06/2018 10:12", "18/06/2018 10:17", 
"18/06/2018 10:20", "18/06/2018 10:25", "18/06/2018 10:29", "18/06/2018 10:32", 
"18/06/2018 10:36", "18/06/2018 10:40", "18/06/2018 10:44", "18/06/2018 10:48", 
"18/06/2018 10:52", "18/06/2018 10:56", "18/06/2018 11:01", "18/06/2018 11:04", 
"18/06/2018 11:09", "18/06/2018 11:12", "18/06/2018 11:17", "18/06/2018 11:22", 
"18/06/2018 11:25", "18/06/2018 11:30", "18/06/2018 11:33", "18/06/2018 11:36", 
"18/06/2018 11:41", "18/06/2018 11:46", "18/06/2018 11:49", "18/06/2018 11:53", 
"18/06/2018 11:56", "18/06/2018 12:01", "18/06/2018 12:05", "18/06/2018 12:09", 
"18/06/2018 12:13", "18/06/2018 12:17", "18/06/2018 12:22", "18/06/2018 12:29", 
"18/06/2018 12:38", "18/06/2018 12:41", "18/06/2018 12:44", "18/06/2018 12:48", 
"18/06/2018 12:52", "18/06/2018 12:56", "18/06/2018 13:00", "18/06/2018 13:04", 
"18/06/2018 13:08", "18/06/2018 13:12", "18/06/2018 13:16", "18/06/2018 13:20", 
"18/06/2018 13:24", "18/06/2018 13:29", "18/06/2018 13:34", "18/06/2018 13:37", 
"18/06/2018 13:40", "18/06/2018 13:44", "18/06/2018 13:48", "18/06/2018 13:52", 
"18/06/2018 13:56", "18/06/2018 14:00", "18/06/2018 14:04", "18/06/2018 14:08", 
"18/06/2018 14:12", "18/06/2018 14:16", "18/06/2018 14:20", "18/06/2018 14:24", 
"18/06/2018 14:29", "18/06/2018 14:32", "18/06/2018 14:36", "18/06/2018 14:40", 
"18/06/2018 14:44", "18/06/2018 14:48", "18/06/2018 14:52", "18/06/2018 14:56", 
"18/06/2018 15:01", "18/06/2018 15:04", "18/06/2018 15:08", "18/06/2018 15:12", 
"18/06/2018 15:16", "18/06/2018 15:21", "18/06/2018 15:24", "18/06/2018 15:28", 
"18/06/2018 15:32", "18/06/2018 15:36", "18/06/2018 15:40", "18/06/2018 15:44", 
"18/06/2018 15:48", "18/06/2018 15:52", "18/06/2018 15:56", "18/06/2018 16:00", 
"18/06/2018 16:04", "18/06/2018 16:08", "18/06/2018 16:12", "18/06/2018 16:16", 
"18/06/2018 16:20", "18/06/2018 16:24", "18/06/2018 16:28", "18/06/2018 16:32", 
"18/06/2018 16:36", "18/06/2018 16:40", "18/06/2018 16:44", "18/06/2018 16:48", 
"18/06/2018 16:52", "18/06/2018 16:56", "18/06/2018 17:00", "18/06/2018 17:04", 
"18/06/2018 17:08", "18/06/2018 17:12", "18/06/2018 17:16", "18/06/2018 17:20", 
"18/06/2018 17:24", "18/06/2018 17:28", "18/06/2018 17:32", "18/06/2018 17:36", 
"18/06/2018 17:40", "18/06/2018 17:44", "18/06/2018 17:48", "18/06/2018 17:52", 
"18/06/2018 17:56", "18/06/2018 18:00", "18/06/2018 18:04", "18/06/2018 18:08", 
"18/06/2018 18:12", "18/06/2018 18:16", "18/06/2018 18:20", "18/06/2018 18:24", 
"18/06/2018 18:28", "18/06/2018 18:32", "18/06/2018 18:36", "18/06/2018 18:40", 
"18/06/2018 18:44", "18/06/2018 18:48", "18/06/2018 18:52", "18/06/2018 18:56", 
"18/06/2018 19:00", "18/06/2018 19:04", "18/06/2018 19:08", "18/06/2018 19:12", 
"18/06/2018 19:16", "18/06/2018 19:20", "18/06/2018 19:24", "18/06/2018 19:28", 
"18/06/2018 19:32", "18/06/2018 19:36", "18/06/2018 19:40", "18/06/2018 19:44", 
"18/06/2018 19:48", "18/06/2018 19:52", "18/06/2018 19:56", "18/06/2018 20:00", 
"18/06/2018 20:04", "18/06/2018 20:08", "18/06/2018 20:12", "18/06/2018 20:16", 
"18/06/2018 20:20", "18/06/2018 20:24", "18/06/2018 20:28", "18/06/2018 20:32", 
"18/06/2018 20:36", "18/06/2018 20:40", "18/06/2018 20:44", "18/06/2018 20:48", 
"18/06/2018 20:52", "18/06/2018 20:56", "18/06/2018 21:00", "18/06/2018 21:04", 
"18/06/2018 21:08", "18/06/2018 21:12", "18/06/2018 21:16", "18/06/2018 21:20", 
"18/06/2018 21:24", "18/06/2018 21:28", "18/06/2018 21:32", "18/06/2018 21:36", 
"18/06/2018 21:40", "18/06/2018 21:44", "18/06/2018 21:48", "18/06/2018 21:52", 
"18/06/2018 21:56", "18/06/2018 22:00", "18/06/2018 22:04", "18/06/2018 22:08", 
"18/06/2018 22:12", "18/06/2018 22:16", "18/06/2018 22:20", "18/06/2018 22:24", 
"18/06/2018 22:28", "18/06/2018 22:32", "18/06/2018 22:36", "18/06/2018 22:40", 
"18/06/2018 22:44", "18/06/2018 22:48", "18/06/2018 22:52", "18/06/2018 22:56", 
"18/06/2018 23:00", "18/06/2018 23:04", "18/06/2018 23:08", "18/06/2018 23:12", 
"18/06/2018 23:16", "18/06/2018 23:20", "18/06/2018 23:24", "18/06/2018 23:28", 
"18/06/2018 23:32", "18/06/2018 23:36", "18/06/2018 23:40", "18/06/2018 23:44", 
"18/06/2018 23:48", "18/06/2018 23:52", "18/06/2018 23:56", "19/06/2018 00:00", 
"19/06/2018 00:04", "19/06/2018 00:08", "19/06/2018 00:12", "19/06/2018 00:16", 
"19/06/2018 00:20", "19/06/2018 00:24", "19/06/2018 00:28", "19/06/2018 00:32", 
"19/06/2018 00:36", "19/06/2018 00:40", "19/06/2018 00:44", "19/06/2018 00:48", 
"19/06/2018 00:52", "19/06/2018 00:56", "19/06/2018 01:00", "19/06/2018 01:04", 
"19/06/2018 01:08", "19/06/2018 01:12", "19/06/2018 01:16", "19/06/2018 01:20", 
"19/06/2018 01:24", "19/06/2018 01:28", "19/06/2018 01:32", "19/06/2018 01:36", 
"19/06/2018 01:40", "19/06/2018 01:44", "19/06/2018 01:48", "19/06/2018 01:52", 
"19/06/2018 01:56", "19/06/2018 02:00", "19/06/2018 02:04", "19/06/2018 02:08", 
"19/06/2018 02:12", "19/06/2018 02:16", "19/06/2018 02:20", "19/06/2018 02:24", 
"19/06/2018 02:28", "19/06/2018 02:32", "19/06/2018 02:36", "19/06/2018 02:40", 
"19/06/2018 02:44", "19/06/2018 02:48", "19/06/2018 02:52", "19/06/2018 02:56", 
"19/06/2018 03:00", "19/06/2018 03:04", "19/06/2018 03:08", "19/06/2018 03:12", 
"19/06/2018 03:16", "19/06/2018 03:20", "19/06/2018 03:24", "19/06/2018 03:28", 
"19/06/2018 03:32", "19/06/2018 03:36", "19/06/2018 03:40", "19/06/2018 03:44", 
"19/06/2018 03:48", "19/06/2018 03:52", "19/06/2018 03:56", "19/06/2018 04:00", 
"19/06/2018 04:04", "19/06/2018 04:08", "19/06/2018 04:12", "19/06/2018 04:16", 
"19/06/2018 04:20", "19/06/2018 04:24", "19/06/2018 04:28", "19/06/2018 04:32", 
"19/06/2018 04:36", "19/06/2018 04:40", "19/06/2018 04:44", "19/06/2018 04:48", 
"19/06/2018 04:52", "19/06/2018 04:56", "19/06/2018 05:00", "19/06/2018 05:04", 
"19/06/2018 05:08", "19/06/2018 05:12", "19/06/2018 05:16", "19/06/2018 05:20", 
"19/06/2018 05:24", "19/06/2018 05:28", "19/06/2018 05:32", "19/06/2018 05:36", 
"19/06/2018 05:40", "19/06/2018 05:44", "19/06/2018 05:48", "19/06/2018 05:52", 
"19/06/2018 05:56", "19/06/2018 06:00", "19/06/2018 06:04", "19/06/2018 06:08", 
"19/06/2018 06:12", "19/06/2018 06:16", "19/06/2018 06:20", "19/06/2018 06:24", 
"19/06/2018 06:28", "19/06/2018 06:32", "19/06/2018 06:36", "19/06/2018 06:40", 
"19/06/2018 06:44", "19/06/2018 06:48", "19/06/2018 06:52", "19/06/2018 06:56", 
"19/06/2018 07:00", "19/06/2018 07:04", "19/06/2018 07:08", "19/06/2018 07:12", 
"19/06/2018 07:16", "19/06/2018 07:20", "19/06/2018 07:24", "19/06/2018 07:28", 
"19/06/2018 07:32", "19/06/2018 07:36", "19/06/2018 07:40", "19/06/2018 07:44", 
"19/06/2018 07:48", "19/06/2018 07:52", "19/06/2018 07:56", "19/06/2018 08:00", 
"19/06/2018 08:04", "19/06/2018 08:08", "19/06/2018 08:12", "19/06/2018 08:16", 
"19/06/2018 08:20", "19/06/2018 08:24", "19/06/2018 08:28", "19/06/2018 08:32", 
"19/06/2018 08:36", "19/06/2018 08:40", "19/06/2018 08:44", "19/06/2018 08:48", 
"19/06/2018 08:52", "19/06/2018 08:56", "19/06/2018 09:00", "19/06/2018 09:04", 
"19/06/2018 09:08", "19/06/2018 09:12", "19/06/2018 09:16", "19/06/2018 09:20", 
"19/06/2018 09:24", "19/06/2018 09:28", "19/06/2018 09:32", "19/06/2018 09:36", 
"19/06/2018 09:40", "19/06/2018 09:44", "19/06/2018 09:48", "19/06/2018 09:52", 
"19/06/2018 09:56", "19/06/2018 10:00", "19/06/2018 10:04", "19/06/2018 10:08", 
"19/06/2018 10:12", "19/06/2018 10:16", "19/06/2018 10:20", "19/06/2018 10:24", 
"19/06/2018 10:28", "19/06/2018 10:32", "19/06/2018 10:36", "19/06/2018 10:40", 
"19/06/2018 10:44", "19/06/2018 10:48", "19/06/2018 10:52", "19/06/2018 10:56", 
"19/06/2018 11:00", "19/06/2018 11:04", "19/06/2018 11:08", "19/06/2018 11:12", 
"19/06/2018 11:16", "19/06/2018 11:21", "19/06/2018 11:24", "19/06/2018 11:28", 
"19/06/2018 11:32", "19/06/2018 11:36", "19/06/2018 11:40", "19/06/2018 11:44", 
"19/06/2018 11:48", "19/06/2018 11:52", "19/06/2018 11:56", "19/06/2018 12:00", 
"19/06/2018 12:04", "19/06/2018 12:08", "19/06/2018 12:12", "19/06/2018 12:16", 
"19/06/2018 12:20", "19/06/2018 12:24", "19/06/2018 12:28", "19/06/2018 12:32", 
"19/06/2018 12:36", "19/06/2018 12:40", "19/06/2018 12:44", "19/06/2018 12:48", 
"19/06/2018 12:52", "19/06/2018 12:56", "19/06/2018 13:00", "19/06/2018 13:04", 
"19/06/2018 13:08", "19/06/2018 13:12", "19/06/2018 13:16", "19/06/2018 13:20", 
"19/06/2018 13:24", "19/06/2018 13:28", "19/06/2018 13:32", "19/06/2018 13:36", 
"19/06/2018 13:40", "19/06/2018 13:44", "19/06/2018 13:48", "19/06/2018 13:52", 
"19/06/2018 13:56", "19/06/2018 14:00", "19/06/2018 14:04", "19/06/2018 14:08", 
"19/06/2018 14:12", "19/06/2018 14:16", "19/06/2018 14:20", "19/06/2018 14:24", 
"19/06/2018 14:28", "19/06/2018 14:32", "19/06/2018 14:36", "19/06/2018 14:40", 
"19/06/2018 14:44", "19/06/2018 14:48", "19/06/2018 14:52", "19/06/2018 14:56", 
"19/06/2018 15:00", "19/06/2018 15:04", "19/06/2018 15:08", "19/06/2018 15:12", 
"19/06/2018 15:16", "19/06/2018 15:20", "19/06/2018 15:24", "19/06/2018 15:28", 
"19/06/2018 15:32", "19/06/2018 15:36", "19/06/2018 15:40", "19/06/2018 15:44", 
"19/06/2018 15:48", "19/06/2018 15:52", "19/06/2018 15:56", "19/06/2018 16:00", 
"19/06/2018 16:04", "19/06/2018 16:08", "19/06/2018 16:12", "19/06/2018 16:16", 
"19/06/2018 16:20", "19/06/2018 16:24", "19/06/2018 16:28", "19/06/2018 16:32", 
"19/06/2018 16:36", "19/06/2018 16:40", "19/06/2018 16:44", "19/06/2018 16:48", 
"19/06/2018 16:52", "19/06/2018 16:56", "19/06/2018 17:00", "19/06/2018 17:04", 
"19/06/2018 17:08", "19/06/2018 17:12", "19/06/2018 17:16", "19/06/2018 17:20", 
"19/06/2018 17:24", "19/06/2018 17:28", "19/06/2018 17:32", "19/06/2018 17:36", 
"19/06/2018 17:40", "19/06/2018 17:44", "19/06/2018 17:48", "19/06/2018 17:52", 
"19/06/2018 17:56", "19/06/2018 18:00", "19/06/2018 18:04", "19/06/2018 18:08", 
"19/06/2018 18:12", "19/06/2018 18:16", "19/06/2018 18:20", "19/06/2018 18:24", 
"19/06/2018 18:28", "19/06/2018 18:32", "19/06/2018 18:36", "19/06/2018 18:40", 
"19/06/2018 18:44", "19/06/2018 18:48", "19/06/2018 18:52", "19/06/2018 18:56", 
"19/06/2018 19:00", "19/06/2018 19:04", "19/06/2018 19:08", "19/06/2018 19:12", 
"19/06/2018 19:16", "19/06/2018 19:20", "19/06/2018 19:24", "19/06/2018 19:28", 
"19/06/2018 19:32", "19/06/2018 19:36", "19/06/2018 19:40", "19/06/2018 19:44", 
"19/06/2018 19:48", "19/06/2018 19:52", "19/06/2018 19:56", "19/06/2018 20:00", 
"19/06/2018 20:04", "19/06/2018 20:08", "19/06/2018 20:12", "19/06/2018 20:16", 
"19/06/2018 20:20", "19/06/2018 20:24", "19/06/2018 20:28", "19/06/2018 20:32", 
"19/06/2018 20:36", "19/06/2018 20:40", "19/06/2018 20:44", "19/06/2018 20:48", 
"19/06/2018 20:52", "19/06/2018 20:56", "19/06/2018 21:00", "19/06/2018 21:04", 
"19/06/2018 21:08", "19/06/2018 21:12", "19/06/2018 21:16", "19/06/2018 21:20", 
"19/06/2018 21:24", "19/06/2018 21:28", "19/06/2018 21:32", "19/06/2018 21:36", 
"19/06/2018 21:40", "19/06/2018 21:44", "19/06/2018 21:48", "19/06/2018 21:52", 
"19/06/2018 21:56", "19/06/2018 22:00", "19/06/2018 22:04", "19/06/2018 22:08", 
"19/06/2018 22:12", "19/06/2018 22:16", "19/06/2018 22:20", "19/06/2018 22:24", 
"19/06/2018 22:28"), meters = c(45.7406821532365, 15.2214084546079, 
15.9593660078151, 22.5355660523, 12.0368343188154, 18.7381339674668, 
26.7818788216134, 8.34165858190966, 11.3327576966507, 15.7369069237407, 
9.72882849925771, 10.297033774998, 4.05410707329196, 2.80921200361505, 
5.99863428254126, 3.43702889630238, 1.0973506459739, 14.9210205443641, 
11.8623534125001, 5.52037842119764, 3.47842432433199, 8.56352953345666, 
10.3348047169779, 4.75068270841804, 10.2158524906783, 8.40843212136055, 
19.176769622017, 8.27181435890216, 4.63398751788878, 4.64609200546047, 
11.2731653163543, 11.4312910706539, 10.532832329052, 9.42036510967477, 
3.72017081997164, 19.1405081193573, 7.62135953649555, 22.0583337290673, 
5.17601163631861, 2.94307133012786, 8.16672175526036, 11.0388731772229, 
8.4520380008427, 14.4121396478424, 9.9917860049159, 15.2689800274799, 
23.5027696734591, 11.5713613868424, 3.76275614223104, 7.44089224335579, 
4.75143353354129, 25.5863700372985, 4.12640308269035, 17.0185845366389, 
9.19416438574403, 0.504992122982213, 7.58240103848382, 15.0141241467732, 
47.820448738411, 48.9253417447483, 28.6982306077959, 30.0325794078543, 
10.6419955753018, 16.3060328028124, 16.9950882683356, 17.5456158130927, 
6.11772166759097, 10.3181549737979, 8.25795394979096, 12.5452581928342, 
7.37344423304636, 14.0784069615297, 15.5217701103853, 5.85740700912933, 
67.5814597516992, 86.1667068274933, 6.71080257210109, 12.8712310356668, 
26.3464242058092, 14.862829937119, 17.1827244506893, 21.007162484455, 
14.6159667602995, 15.0116767634002, 3.44415089036116, 2.90091354423872, 
15.4060076069905, 11.0647299060198, 5.47803214985054, 21.4699825151886, 
13.9952170296303, 5.47503135778305, 9.59949901256039, 2.67150469440983, 
5.81615251769606, 18.7977607686961, 17.1405856185114, 0.770680478662077, 
2.11599500699301, 14.4215651159807, 21.340644921803, 9.44803939591664, 
9.35914024298419, 26.5419236409891, 12.2076659835784, 11.6727676178834, 
11.5183958294441, 11.1464930265903, 4.48800980044162, 14.5010190190289, 
17.9964315949038, 6.19790617124279, 11.4579719854227, 7.02888318334768, 
2.43292600920741, 7.09331125112953, 7.41769642742311, 6.15912646167791, 
6.17702835583737, 5.50679980253089, 27.2967339245239, 26.809594968574, 
16.6454622873968, 6.74805054317244, 5.69175256676157, 5.28218041234659, 
7.75355680259654, 9.13245480739586, 17.2138677622628, 30.8757344431557, 
10.4532031567326, 6.64426961601855, 7.62833591252156, 67.2325093819334, 
58.8815117188855, 14.67853688946, 10.4197239865493, 25.850404929181, 
14.8215484542981, 17.8354868952429, 4.53929715323194, 2.49940267894446, 
7.15430231148364, 9.79764663049093, 11.2388351166403, 4.22708779610617, 
13.1226888741628, 6.86582195506769, 21.0333162925842, 24.2027940323749, 
15.164801715416, 20.8875492434141, 10.8583121642675, 17.9399411230084, 
23.4730382740048, 11.7208011931361, 6.08657685375735, 19.4111128168678, 
15.6735709416045, 15.4027288613498, 14.7406668388859, 4.21308837483828, 
6.9823143969642, 3.72864795928499, 17.4100339528372, 19.5473631918946, 
11.7404262614498, 11.6668635506407, 4.51437593270175, 25.5020957862817, 
2.42357811960285, 16.8353939403993, 7.85156097432205, 18.1401928118823, 
1.14240586696655, 28.0586180742577, 59.6003755600272, 741.364692233718, 
2451.03176274837, 1924.25225046211, 91.0077010587984, 129.914778093003, 
23.7263560261478, 19.2052584330969, 31.2431026776704, 303.356757432854, 
69.3573791615057, 79.2353341460047, 40.001574391757, 125.241489048742, 
0.875997360851126, 101.761469702257, 14.3803188275614, 19.3916155295248, 
16.5485908318872, 36.7050416049996, 2.28524732255712, 59.3064322763378, 
97.7492244922703, 2.4560922159233, 18.9182418683955, 29.1775598809323, 
72.8131889738511, 0.536696681632468, 1.66920881986582, 1.1474807643325, 
1.00624417050841, 34.7753323815772, 13.1764541914541, 0.987640444852192, 
46.8576255846636, 12.6260387130311, 0.981930298073766, 0, 95.5457420387006, 
36.4423832793374, 11.3666824424413, 14.6529671509152, 11.6555883294269, 
22.7960129030282, 2.49939892511722, 2.1865821808201, 9.09470367692037, 
52.9342974939483, 6.47968205299305, 1.08340934139405, 0.560041122020628, 
0.536696441270263, 1.32908923984974, 0.86507269221477, 1.22330477453381, 
70.0552350787317, 12.3451237647639, 3.11666258579037, 1.93736182424659, 
3.51794257381499, 1.32908899309918, 2.31154944415652, 0.834805281491471, 
1.64638218465927, 0.504255396690464, 3.17394653919415, 1.75132408931791, 
1.49111519239348, 2.73481993931031, 2.00143073945307, 1.4365841848048, 
1.37960800380212, 2.8231207877357, 2.27843509169923, 22.1135221191054, 
9.09386309784055, 1.63627180145216, 6.40111320930751, 7.05302865648799, 
7.19422051080435, 4.25534285783686, 1.94331689005661, 0.981930279418075, 
2.18872974709499, 1.30702979274852, 1.01730181071795, 0.25351813244195, 
1.01094711070046, 2.63413039676338, 1.97998436214355, 1.95035919800779, 
0.800780147342046, 1.71618874492291, 1.14748009836729, 2.09171118450703, 
3.35928280239732, 2.69012333124418, 2.61191486817587, 7.44266937655, 
1.02601599075127, 2.84418905758968, 1.96914434184303, 2.78048662570437, 
1.93865533359675, 3.1881307017127, 12.9836375626473, 2.03466874517043, 
3.2650256164747, 5.49720574599675, 3.16684326703025, 3.61040117444932, 
2.4393235459518, 4.41349847491449, 1.39024319239671, 1.70331614558013, 
1.1894815496101, 2.07256571088354, 0, 1.31556162525377, 0.3269295629247, 
1.2315075039072, 1.12985048401375, 4.12639695258049, 3.53057858117975, 
1.14689379910243, 1.89463915995567, 0.326929561525381, 2.12981387194087, 
0.29095890697518, 1.69583706057361, 1.12824512647375, 2.63413021072766, 
2.46969082725569, 1.69695134562863, 6.60037145525014, 4.08280291298734, 
1.91314714385751, 4.10209917791834, 2.44808743796531, 58.5958105549192, 
49.0573915168004, 1.71618923544311, 2.16623234264144, 33.7528092143734, 
1.26876292628825, 4.09301793236524, 6.47380341213986, 2.02287444044928, 
6.15764791418056, 4.88198337685391, 6.1518534564327, 19.9293981357374, 
31.2807443706163, 11.9760177553429, 7.80034538189425, 2.09856685581426, 
15.5559610933875, 5.54425190776513, 4.31727752887657, 1.69695203818687, 
3.13701726469391, 4.17079079435503, 0, 0.253518261190509, 0.768515387271088, 
5.75312128614323, 1.10161787301914, 0, 1.63627263077218, 1.94331762790558, 
0.984128914771002, 0, 1.891376142142, 1.88169045315321, 1.14968339087591, 
1.94662436122789, 2.53667294419711, 2.22463784687921, 1.14716037069784, 
1.72269599615416, 0.253518262766866, 0.557086177521366, 0.834805798848609, 
0.834805798848609, 0.834805798848609, 0.32373515360376, 0.250851604274291, 
1.13037794205011, 1.01730179938836, 1.08245009766703, 1.29008139493895, 
0.592050658495912, 0.984128914593752, 1.14716037069784, 0.246921421310107, 
1.08086752437222, 0, 0.253518261190127, 0.834146432905571, 0.834146432905571, 
1.32088856328962, 0, 1.01730179951988, 0.557086174016414, 0, 
0, 0.981930302577223, 1.01730179952143, 0.801467385970428, 1.891376142142, 
0.984128914771002, 0.984128914771002, 1.891376142142, 1.31556194378487, 
1.70331684297699, 11.4746462151774, 5.19876037652309, 18.1991232643532, 
5.45048803468078, 3.50474735760544, 0.834439563061093, 0, 1.29008140210492, 
0.984760642562075, 1.01730179907391, 32.657190675824, 39.7593130805261, 
34.2547425122791, 12.1116764053771, 18.526009117261, 3.86538989203226, 
7.07005984938157, 1.72929805654892, 6.73320732100181, 23.0796824899771, 
66.8539968083065, 101.031538229766, 142.563193250685, 117.93396678646, 
30.4231296530894, 43.3196594211314, 14.3288406144688, 6.01740959634099, 
7.35496556381327, 7.0780957149326, 1.06782836828317, 10.3553242863905, 
59.205976673877, 34.5440414717095, 90.5195981896788, 32.8711449150829, 
3.40710213072646, 6.60140695190154, 20.751091499863, 1.89137226358219, 
2.83321448749677, 26.5437774761593, 4.78947844059108, 15.9299548924479, 
3.49392462916022, 0.834803361386949, 53.9702480435499, 44.7123678229481, 
4.58801253896994, 9.09964716760873, 52.4316347054904, 83.5342865610675, 
4.66725660885041, 12.5978430947004, 1.94751698101872, 0.504253850871525, 
3.45174941271515, 1.63626628055968, 5.40488600424627, 12.3995886978579, 
16.9313577940681, 3.91617610821253, 4.70252672649754, 17.2466244205231, 
5.87640930205112, 7.83322335835387, 68.1235163864855, 3.42589865816882, 
13.1957354034354, 11.2205841718684, 1.01730188003348, 2.08209678645147, 
2.82727432802774, 32.5321887823726, 12.067922456633, 1.8035643067272, 
1.2090985158482, 2.5520360706561, 3.727677427748, 18.1658365688268, 
2.53389262037358, 4.5038564350202, 3.99153396380181, 26.3513692155869, 
52.630041380923, 53.0536675276293, 43.8202570822247, 17.9563768133082, 
35.8843410313514, 2.52741128965252, 2.07122243755901, 61.1369106676384, 
31.0602902769797, 1.93735691953792, 1.39063392798036, 4.74080462885894, 
1.83677904498507, 1.5837058884799, 24.8779450701876, 1.02751235639547, 
5.21277171962475, 5.88014964276792, 7.13082208780676, 1.84782941870358, 
4.28412823329233, 4.8726754921709, 1.80492747976475, 0.834142917601792, 
12.8071661996776, 45.7714211143098, 14.9358063376832, 117.774596740257, 
1.94331089207628, 2.89950585430524, 1.55188895271854, 1.97146416004927, 
3.62849282585251, 0.682586430353306, 1.14715895538192, 84.973523683883, 
16.6260802285038, 5.17522902371143, 2.99113461676237, 7.1948737543452, 
2.71109872104149, 4.22696799241781, 4.53907546305565, 5.71728738868701, 
8.68379208483034, 3.75585732758793, 4.82085426327032, 5.81439758874005, 
3.39028745288001, 3.55051027017038, 60.2330430998918, 38.3544603220122, 
1.21375339001644, 1.91785016319426, 0.3237336743715, 1.69694647561642, 
1.14877752688831, 2.37357312547656, 0, 0.909047979716786, 1.08244477955533, 
3.35946823082954, 2.16622390570235, 1.9688553226609, 1.13578000777225, 
1.63525542752795, 1.48883000783912, 2.83467921372661, 2.12754007740878, 
17.3540112473834, 6.32166165556282, 1.94746224312546, 14.5084951818398, 
3.71993035536828, 3.82335882963004, 2.84750706444208, 0, 1.71618366510756, 
0.323733628303048, 6.97407775313294, 27.9890313303321, 2.18646977811563, 
2.96545099539278, 0, 2.00143091430776, 14.0439085683219, 0.25351711418234, 
1.69380290439435, 2.28323132482563, 3.85986892850026, 2.69197208488191, 
2.22437966566857, 9.49208589978412, 49.4880243971914, 100.881212266528, 
5.84222371086618, 85.6548691469987, 0.834143439442611, 71.1685884754485, 
10.0799187801841, 37.4349094205841, 3.96457080819355, 8.02426971700344, 
2.64427066449314, 11.2298595430791, 19.152210952781, 25.9621194522378, 
2.43632829382703, 6.05555098063067, 154.726395809777, 18.7647119416837, 
27.2616358671239, 11.5922993940012, 68.2775157158671, 49.1853059189567, 
35.5259047498724, 28.1895151756555, 11.2830643554028, 70.5225858134716, 
33.761787160485, 9.92505257193424, 12.2487708385319, 4.72780789239903, 
2.36949301171681, 0.898029677765623, 1.41928645304406, 1.98000060537725, 
7.46921332355175, 2.93628219004468, 3.6470392684573, 1.10014488207181, 
4.92479363929599, 14.8930755174664, 5.83901213703915, 1.72269354554739, 
7.485351543375, 5.3630772018188, 14.5613108033135, 6.95128356614464, 
2.84031328921816, 8.22896775502526, 0.990766534590514, 6.06503541796136, 
15.9514929128702, 13.8886767897834, 13.6568135914468, 4.37835160159707, 
17.4136820914597, 10.9348080118824, 5.78925441619791, 1.96886057231489, 
3.1381105751168, 3.00555214539433, 8.65031990810392, 18.0889311952119, 
4.9279620177745, 6.53967791518033, 5.12248780673471, 9.65327444852992, 
2.90279381701306, 3.25053402550702, 0.178554668218116, 2.11296628947042, 
0, 2.05463008665439, 3.28780487743892, 3.27975197232669, 1.11688313023969, 
3.54263761112745, 3.44538669236583, 3.26397986165939, 2.09856659919216, 
5.37139341320134, 5.6924115655593, 4.60202445590286)), row.names = c(NA, 
-650L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000051e1ef0>)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the crossover/allocation (e.g. how do you allocate from say `2018-06-15 03:55` if the next row is `2018-06-15 04:02` with 10 meters?) then you could do something simple like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    date = dmy_hm(date),
    hour = hour(date)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(hour) %>%
  summarise(
    avg_meters = mean(meters)
  )

# A tibble: 24 x 2
    hour avg_meters
   <int>      <dbl>
 1     0      12.3 
 2     1       7.62
 3     2       1.36
 4     3       7.92
 5     4       4.33
 6     5       8.06
 7     6      29.7 
 8     7      18.9 
 9     8      19.8 
10     9      11.5 
# ... with 14 more rows
```

Which you could then add:

```
%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hour, y = avg_meters)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. With this method then, what happens to the crossover allocation issue? Does the disance get alocated to the previous or next hour if the interval is in between an hour sharp?

Comment: The row with `03:55` would get assigned to hour 3; row with `04:02` would get assigned to hour 4. So something on the hour, like `04:00` would still get assigned to hour 4.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I am wondering however if I was clear enough about how I would like the code to perform. Because the original `datanet` dataset has calculated distance travelled every 4 minutes aprox. in the column `meters`; does your code then calculate the hourly average by averaging all 4 minute intervals within that hourly interval or does it sum up all the distances travelled every 4 minutes within an hourly interval?

Comment: @juancda4 as it's written, it averages all the distances that occurred within a given a hour. In the future, it can be helpful to post your expected / desired results along with the example (of course, you may want to also consider using a smaller, but representative dataset).

Comment: Right. Thank you for your help. I was wondering if there's a quick way where I could also get the sum of all the distances that occurred within a given hour? I guess it can be done by using almost the same code?

Comment: @juancda4 yes, just change the summarise statement to `summarise( avg_meters = mean(meters), sum_meters = sum(meters) )` - the `dplyr` package is especially useful for this type of work; `lubridate` can assist with all the time and date-part calculations.